# bivariate skew normal distribution in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, skew

Can anyone tell me a good way to fit a bivariate skew normal distribution in R? I've looked at packages such as "sn" and "fMultivar" but these have not proven useful. Thank you.

Comment: Provide data so we can see what you mean by the verb "fit". I cannot tell what criteria is to be used. Is this some sort of regression problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use msn.mple() function in the 'sn' package. Suppose your data is y, which is an n by 2 data frame/matrix. Then just use:

`msn.mple(y)` or `msn.mple(y, penalty='Qpenalty')`

When the sample size is small, it is suggested to use penalty='Qpenalty' option to avoid the exploding estimator on the shape parameter.